# how to create table in google Bigtable

Tags: java

i want to create table in google big table using java and servelt code?
how to create table and insert into  Google big table database?
I want sample coding to create table in Google big table?

Answer (score 2):

Google does not give public access to Bigtable.

Are you talking about the Datastore for App Engine (which runs on Bigtable)? If so, there is lots of documentation over at the App Engine developer site, in particular [Getting Started For Java: Using the Datastore with JDO](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/java/gettingstarted/usingdatastore.html).

Answer (score 1):

Six years later, it is now possible. Take a look at this Quickstart page for how to get a Bigtable instance and start writing to it
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/quickstart

And then here is a sample "Hello, World!" application
https://cloud.google.com/bigtable/docs/samples-java-hello

For example

```
  try (Connection connection = BigtableConfiguration.connect(projectId, instanceId)) {

      Admin admin = connection.getAdmin();

      HTableDescriptor descriptor = new HTableDescriptor(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME));
      descriptor.addFamily(new HColumnDescriptor(COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME));

      print("Create table " + descriptor.getNameAsString());
      admin.createTable(descriptor);

      Table table = connection.getTable(TableName.valueOf(TABLE_NAME));

      print("Write some greetings to the table");
      for (int i = 0; i < GREETINGS.length; i++) {
        String rowKey = "greeting" + i;

        Put put = new Put(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey));
        put.addColumn(COLUMN_FAMILY_NAME, COLUMN_NAME, Bytes.toBytes(GREETINGS[i]));
        table.put(put);
      }

      String rowKey = "greeting0";
      Result getResult = table.get(new Get(Bytes.toBytes(rowKey)));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a google of Hadoop (http://hadoop.apache.org/) - and the hadoop based Hbase (http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/Hbase). These are similar-in-concept implementations to google's bigtable. If you cannot readily use these libraries, then you are out of luck.